# Calling newsletter short code in static block stop showing the form

Tags: magento-1.9

I am calling newsletter in static block by below sort code

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" }}
```

its was working, but suddenly stopped to show the form. I have checked the permission for `newsletter/subscribe` in permission section where it is set to "allow" as well.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @Klettseb i did not change any thing..all my static block sort code stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I took me a while to found out why the block tag isn't showing the newsletter, but you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420285/newsletter-signup-on-cms-page-in-magento

Like epson121 mentioned, you have to enable the block in CMS -> Permissions (or add it, if it's not there).

The block name is of course: newsletter/subscribe