# Newsletter in Static Block Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.1, static-block, newsletter

I need to add default newsletter form in a static block. I have tried the following short codes:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="subscribe.phtml"}}
```

None of them work. However if I use:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('subscribe'); ?>
```

inside the `footer.phtml` of my theme it works. Ideally I want to add this to a block in Magento 2. The block is defined properly in the theme and rest of the content of the block shows properly.

Some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420285/newsletter-signup-on-cms-page-in-magento) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112893/calling-newsletter-short-code-in-static-block-stop-showing-the-form) say that some block permissions need to be given to use this. I don't see anything `System > Permissions > Blocks` or `System -> Advanced -> Advanced` in Magento 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You almost had it. Here's the code you need to use:

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Awesome. This works perfectly. It's strange that I couldn't find this even after googling it for 2+ hours. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Magento 1 code in Magento 2. For this issue you can call it like :

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="any_name" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

Comment: In magento 1.9 what code? @Ashish Jagnani

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="subscribe_form.phtml"}}
```